# Homework in Java. Find the largest product of five consecutive digits

Tags: java, algorithm

We have started learning Java in school, and we have been given a few homeworks to do. I've managed to do 4 out of 5, but this last one is a real pain.

Basicly: Write a program that finds (in a 1000 places long number) the largest product of five
consecutive digits.

Here's the number http://pastebin.com/PFgL6jcM

Do you have any ideas how to solve this ?

If this are unclear instruction, notify me and will try to explain to you again.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Can you do this for a smaller number?

Comment: You mean you should compute the first block of 5 then the second one, then... or try from the first digit, then the second etc?

Comment: Can you tell us more about where you're getting stuck? We could answer it for you, but that would defeat the purpose of homework ;-)

Comment: I'm having problem if I should put this number in an array and then go with a for loop through the array. Or is there a more simpler idea with a String ?

Comment: This is [Problem 8](http://projecteuler.net/problem=8) from Project Euler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say an optimized algorithm would look like this:

1) grab first five numbers

2) if current set contains a `0`, grab the first five numbers after the `0`. Do this until you reach a set that doesn't contain a `0`. (if all sets contain a `0` - unlikely - return `0`).

3) compute the product of the 5 numbers ( `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4`, `x5` ) like so:

```
p1 = x5 * x4
p2 = x3 * p1
p3 = x2 * p2
p  = x1 * p3
```

4) if `p` is greater than the previous `p`, store it.

5) discard the first number and add the next one (`x6`).

```
p = x6 * p3
```

6) if the new `p` is greater than the old one, go to step 3)

**You're reducing the number of multiplications by a factor of 5, since you won't keep multiplying 5 numbers, but 2.**

Remember to discard sequences that contain a `0` and try to optimize the algorithm along these lines.

Comment: This fails with the following sequence:  9,1,1,1,1,1

Comment: it should be 9,2,1,1,1,1 sorry.  The output ends up being 0 for the first p and 2 for the second p

Comment: @Woot4Moo it was a typo, should be `*` instead of `&`. The first `p` is thus 18.

Comment: Thank you Luchian. You have been very helpful. This is my Java version. It works alright http://pastebin.com/Tfu6D7j1 .

Answer (score 5):

The most naive approach is to just use a sort of "sliding window" over the number. Window is of size 5 and you keep track of the maximum number:

1. the window starts with the first 5 digits
2. multiply the 5 digits in the window and compare to the current max. If larger, update the current max, and probably store the index as well if you want to track which numbers were just to retrieve that max
3. shift the window one digit and start from top

A possible optimization which immediately comes to mind  is that you can skip the second step if the window contains a zero. Even better, you can immediately shift the window until the first digit behind the zero.

Comment: I think my variant provides more optimization. :)

Comment: Even better scan from right to left and stop when you reach the beginning or see a zero :).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by consecutive, you mean 5 digits out of the large number you've provided.

You will want to loop through each of the characters in the number one at a time, grab the next four digits after it, find the product. If it's higher than the last product, store it and the 5 digit combination, then move to the next digit until you've processed all of the digits.

Comment: This is completely inefficient.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not going to provide optimizations for a homework assignment.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I'm not convinced it's inefficient. Multiplications are cheap, I wouldn't be surprised if it's faster than the load of branchings needed to avoid a couple of multiplications. But for 1000 digits, we're talking about microseconds anyway.

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought that was the point of the question... a brute-force approach was obvious - or so I thought.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore You can hardly believe all the things that are not obvious to many people :) I have seen prime tests that divide all the way up to `n-1` and don't break out of the loop when a divisor is found. Written by professional programmers.

Answer (score -1):

Convert the number to a String;

Convert the String to an array of characters;

Convert the character array to an integer array;

Set a value to 0;

Loop though each integer until the 5th to last character;

**(in loop)** Multiply that integer with the next 4 integers in the array;

**(in loop)** If the result is greater than the value you're holding onto then replace it with the product of the 5 numbers;

(end of the loop)

I'm not writing it out for you... it's your homework ;)

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem asked.  Why are you summing an element with it's following 4 elements? Did you mean multiply them?