# Code doesn't show correct product c#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm studying coding and I'm on project 8 of project euler.
I was able to show the product "5832" for four adjacent digits when I'm using my code however when I use it on 13 digits, it doesn't work. My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace practice
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        const string number = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

        string input1, input2, input3, input4, input5;
        string input6, input7, input8, input9, input10;
        string input11, input12, input13;

        int convert1, convert2, convert3, convert4, convert5;
        int convert6, convert7, convert8, convert9, convert10;
        int convert11, convert12, convert13;

        convert1 = convert2 = convert3 = convert4 = convert5 = convert6 = convert7 = convert8 = 0;
        convert9 = convert10 = convert11 = convert12 = convert13 = 0;



        int counter;
        int product = 0;
        int largest = 0;
        int length = number.Length - 13;

        for (counter = 1; counter <= length; counter++)
        {
            input1 = number.Substring(counter, 1);
            input2 = number.Substring(counter+1, 1);
            input3 = number.Substring(counter+2, 1);
            input4 = number.Substring(counter+3, 1);
            input5 = number.Substring(counter+4, 1);
            input6 = number.Substring(counter+5, 1);
            input7 = number.Substring(counter+6, 1);
            input8 = number.Substring(counter+7, 1);
            input9 = number.Substring(counter+8, 1);
            input10 = number.Substring(counter+9, 1);
            input11 = number.Substring(counter+10, 1);
            input12 = number.Substring(counter+11, 1);
            input13 = number.Substring(counter+12, 1);


            convert1 = Convert.ToInt32(input1);
            convert2 = Convert.ToInt32(input2);
            convert3 = Convert.ToInt32(input3);
            convert4 = Convert.ToInt32(input4);
            convert5 = Convert.ToInt32(input5);
            convert6 = Convert.ToInt32(input6);
            convert7 = Convert.ToInt32(input7);
            convert8 = Convert.ToInt32(input8);
            convert9 = Convert.ToInt32(input9);
            convert10 = Convert.ToInt32(input10);
            convert11 = Convert.ToInt32(input11);
            convert12 = Convert.ToInt32(input12);
            convert13 = Convert.ToInt32(input13);

            product = convert1 * convert2 * convert3 * convert4 * convert5 * convert6
                * convert7 * convert8 * convert9 * convert10 * convert11
                * convert12 * convert13;
            if (largest < product) { largest = product; }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("The largest number is {0}", largest);
       Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

It doesn't show the correct answer which I find daunting. The next steps 
I did is: 
1. Check the last 13 digits of my variables to check if it loops and multiplies correctly "0420420752963450". 
2. Check if it works with the first four numbers and first five numbers which are surprisingly correct. 
3. Studied how others have done it. 
4. Links used: 
[Homework in Java. Find the largest product of five consecutive digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734009/homework-in-java-find-the-largest-product-of-five-consecutive-digits) 
http://www.mathblog.dk/solution-to-problem-8-of-project-euler/

I seem to not get it. Please guide me on seeing my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `product` variable is `int` and you parse your consecutive numbers to `int`. Max value for integer is 2,147,483,647. So when you multiply 13 numbers it's quite possible you will exceed the limit and the value will overflow giving incorrect result. Perhaps, consider using `BigInteger` instead.

Comment: `long` or `ulong` should give you enough wiggle room to do the math.

Comment: Basically any type that allows you to store up to 9^13. `BigInteger` can be helpful if the task escalate to something more crazy than 13.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
   [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        const string number = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

        int index = 0;
        int largest = 0;
        var largestString = "";
        const int length = 13;

        while (index + length <= number.Length)
        {
            var substring = number.Substring(index, length);
            var product = ProductOfEachNumber(substring);
            if (product > largest)
            {
                largestString = substring;
                largest = product;
            }
            index++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The largest number is {0}", largest);
        Console.WriteLine("The largest number string is {0}", largestString);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestSubstring()
    {
        var res = ProductOfEachNumber("9989");
        res.Should().Be(5832);
    }
    private static int ProductOfEachNumber(string substring)
    {
        return substring.Aggregate(1, (current, c) => current*Int32.Parse(c.ToString()));
    }
```

Gives output:

```
The largest number is 2091059712
The largest number string is 9781797784617
```

Comment: I also got 2091059712, however, the answer in project euler is a different number. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, let me know. You have to modify it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        int x = Largest();
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.WriteLine("Time used (float): {0} ms", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Time used (rounded): {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static int Largest()
    {
        string p = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
        int largest = 0;
        int numm = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < p.Length - 4; i++)
        {
            numm = int.Parse(p.Substring(i, 1)) *
                       int.Parse(p.Substring(i + 1, 1)) *
                       int.Parse(p.Substring(i + 2, 1)) *
                       int.Parse(p.Substring(i + 3, 1)) *
                       int.Parse(p.Substring(i + 4, 1));
            if (numm > largest)
            {
                largest = numm;
            }
        }
        return largest;
    }
```